# How to rds connection drops when downscaling?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

I’m thinking of using autoscaling with my Amazon aurora postgres, but I’m worried about what to do if a replica is downscaling and a client still holds a connection to that replica. How can I make sure that the client can handle this situation?

Comment: Is the client connecting to the load-balanced Aurora Reader endpoint? Or directly to a specific Aurora instance? Also, what is your client exactly? JDBC, ODBC, etc? There are guides for handling this depending on what your client is.

Comment: Its a JDBC client. Its connecting directly to an aurora reader at the moment

Comment: As documented here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/Aurora.Connecting.html you should use the AWS Aurora JDBC wrapper: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-advanced-jdbc-wrapper and you should really connect to the load balanced reader endpoint instead of directly to a single instance.

Answer (score 0):

The connection is based on TCP, and once it's disconnected, the JDBC drive opens a new TCP connection to the RDS instance.

I can recommend using AWS RDS Proxy - it holds the connection pool to the application and takes care of the connections to the backend.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/rds-proxy.html

Also, AWS have provided their own JDBC connector, which is recommended for faster recovery https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc